# How to write/read to unknown input/output stream in c++

Tags: c++, stream

I need my program to do one of the following:

1. Read from standard input and write to standard output
2. Read from given file and write to another given file

The way of work is only determined in run-time.

This is what I tried

```
void runProgram(std::istream programIStream, std::ostream programOStream)
{
    int x;
    programIStream >> x; // Reading from program input stream

    programOStream << "Writing to program output stream" << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc == 3)
    {
        std::ifstream ifs;
        ifs.open(argv[1], std::ios::in);
        std::ofstream ofs;
        ofs.open(argv[2], std::ios::out);
        runProgram(ifs, ofs);
    }
    else
    {
        runProgram(std::cin, std::cout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I assumed that inheritance will take care of everything, but this doesn't work.

What is the proper way to do what I need?

Comment: You need to pass by reference: `void runProgram(std::istream& programIStream, std::ostream& programOStream)`

Comment: Search for: object slicing.

Comment: @NathanOliver, this solves it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To actually do this, you have to something like this (pass by reference):

```
void runProgram(std::istream& programIStream, std::ostream& programOStream)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `programIStream` and `programOStream` by value.
This is the error clang throws when compiling your code (as for std::istream) :

```
error: call to deleted constructor of 'std::istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>')
...
note: declared protected here
   basic_istream(const basic_istream&) = delete;
```

This constructor is called [a copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor). It is marked as explicitly deleted, which means this situation totally shouldn't happen.

[Pass a reference of them instead.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bcb23a6f1c0d775)